# Solving a PHP which does not store an input?

Tags: javascript, php, html

The context:
On my website users can customize clothing products. Along the customer funnel, it is asked to the user to input a quantity. This quantity is then used when our team receives the order to generate a quote. Nevertheless, it appears that the quantity is not stored as it always returns 1, even when the user inputs another number e.g. 100. I cannot find a way to solve this.

Below you will find code parts that include the quantity dimension. If you see any corrections to be made feel free to mention them.

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'epopey_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 3);
function epopey_wc_add_to_cart_message_html ( $message, $products, $show_qty ){
    $titles = array();
    if ( ! is_array( $products ) ) {
        $products = array( $products => 1 );
    }
    if ( ! $show_qty ) {
        $products = array_fill_keys( array_keys( $products ), 1 );
    }

    foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
        /* translators: %s: product name */
        $titles[] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_qty_html', ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ), $product_id ) . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_item_name_in_quotes', sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) ), $product_id );
        $count   += $qty;
    }

    $titles = array_filter( $titles );
```

Backorder notification

```
if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
    echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'norebro' ) . '</p>';
}
?>
                                    </h4>
                                </td>

                                <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'norebro' ); ?>">
<?php
if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
    $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
} else {
    $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                            'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                            'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                            'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                            'min_value'   => '0'
                            ), $_product, false );
}

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
?>
                            </td>
```

email details to customer

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <?php
        $qty          = $item->get_quantity();
        $refunded_qty = $order->get_qty_refunded_for_item( $item_id );

        if ( $refunded_qty ) {
            $qty_display = '<del>' . esc_html( $qty ) . '</del> <ins>' . esc_html( $qty - ( $refunded_qty * -1 ) ) . '</ins>';
        } else {
            $qty_display = esc_html( $qty );
        }
        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $qty_display, $item ) );
        ?>
    </td>
```

order details

```
    <td class="product-quantity">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '%s', $item->get_quantity() ) . '</strong>', $item ); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php if ( $show_purchase_note && $purchase_note ) : ?>
<tr class="product-purchase-note">
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>

Table with order details

        <table class="woo-my-orders-table woo-details woo-my-content">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'norebro' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'norebro' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                    $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
    
                    wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-item.php', array(
                        'order'              => $order,
                        'item_id'            => $item_id,
                        'item'               => $item,
                        'show_purchase_note' => $show_purchase_note,
                        'purchase_note'      => $product ? get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_purchase_note', true ) : '',
                        'product'            => $product,
                    ) );
                }
            ?>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_items_table', $order ); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Congrats if you read until here, hope there is enough details. Thanks for your time and help.

### Edit #1

Could the below code lines be a starting point to solve the problem ?

**HTML**

```
<div type="submit" class="wc-proceed-to-checkout" onClick="quantitySubmit(this.form)">
<a href="https://epopey.co/validation-du-devis/" class="btn full-width brand-bg-color brand-border-color brand-color-hover text-center">Valider le devis</a>
```

**JS**

```
function quantitySubmit(form){
    return (form.submit()){
    window.location.href = "https://epopey.co/validation-du-devis/"
    }

    else {
    text = "Please input a number"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough info/details here, actually. Your theme has a file called `woocommerce-hack.js` where your quantity is being set in the html. I didn't get to where the value is actually passed to the backend yet - but what you have above isn't the whole picture.

Comment: What elements could be shared to make the whole picture available ?

Comment: Look at the process between the page with your cart with the quantity selection and it's interaction with the backend as it moves to the "verification" page (I think, chrome was having a hard time translating french). The input value is updated correctly by js, but that value isn't making it to your server. aka whatever reads that input is either over writing with 1, or never reading it at all and defaulting. Sorry not enough time to go further than that today (for me).

Answer (score 0):

The page that allows a change in quantity isn't updating the cart when it moves to the validate quote page. The button that was added to link to that page doesn't first perform the woo commerce cart update. See below:
[image: no show html]

The input of type `submit` must be "clicked" so the page can post back to itself and update the cart before the browser is redirected to the new page.

I'd recommend a simple javascript function in the `onclick` attribute of the div (class = `wc-proceed-to-checkout`) that submits the form and returns true/false on success/failure and allows redirection to "https://epopey.co/validation-du-devis/" for success and gives whatever error message you decide on failure.

To redirect in JS: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

If you need help writing the javascript to submit your form and handle the return value, search for answers on this site, I know they exist/also on Google.

There are numerous other ways to solve this as well - hard to give a best practice answer without knowing your code base/the structure of the theme. Hopefully identifying the problem is enough for you to solve on your own.

TLDR; your validate quote button overrides a default submission button to update the cart with increased/decreased quantities. Make sure the form on this page posts before the page is redirected to the next, or you'll lose the changed quantities.